# Python Scipy.integrate.solve_ivp returns Initial solution, or very few points compared to what it was asked to integrate

Tags: math, scipy, ode

I was trying to avoid asking this, because I can't really build a MWE, so I'm going to put the minimum part of the code needed with the results:

The function that is being integrated:
(it takes one variable `r` and a 5x1 array `z` to return  a 5x1 array `dz/dr`

```
def FUNs(r_p,z):
    return np.array([complex(DER(r_p,z)),complex(DBTH(r_p,z)),complex(DPR(r_p,z)),complex(DUF(r_p,z)),complex(DUR(r_p,z))])
```

the starting point `r0,z0` with its  `FUNs(r0,z0)` are respectively:

`r0:3`

`z0 : [0.1428571428571428, 0.7142857142857144, -4.285714285714286, 0.032798740408674976, -0.07511922913583222]`

and

`FUNs(r0,z0) : array([ 10.25070341+0.j, -14.01473929+0.j,   0.26616247+0.j, 0.51135355+0.j,   0.08613425+0.j])`

To the execution part:

I just call the solve_ivp to integrate lets say a very small space `3.00 -> 3.01` using the follow commands:

```
start  = 3.0
limit  = 3.01
t_get  = np.linspace(start,limit,10)
z00    = z0
sol    = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(FUNs, [start, limit], z00, method='RK45',t_eval=t_get, vectorized=False,rtol=10**(-8.5),atol=10**(-8.5))
```

and to check that the integration fails, the `space` that the integration goes through is given by `sol.t` which is :

```
sol.t >>> array([3.        , 3.00111111, 3.00222222, 3.00333333])
```

If I go wild  with `limit = 4` or something `sol.t` gives just `3.` xD

Any help is appreciated

PS.

`sol.message` gives this output : `'Required step size is less than spacing between numbers.'`

Comment: What is the content of `sol.message`?

Comment: what? sol.t shows the space point the integration  has gone through, while sol.y is the solution through each of those points. @LutzLehmann

Comment: And `sol.success` tells if the integration was performed successfully, and `sol.message` contains the error message. See documentation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry for not responding, but , even though its close to unbelievable my laptop just died and I literally can't run the SAME script on my desktop no matter how much I'm trying. I will answer as soon as I fix it

Comment: @LutzLehmann I added the sol.message on Question. If you are still there :) TY for your time

Comment: This looks typical for a singularity. Are the values for `sol.y[-1]` still nice or out of any sensible bound? Do there exist "physical" reasons to expect a nicely bounded ongoing solution? Then there may be an error in the ODE functions. Check them again against the theory, try to separate long expressions into compact sub-expressions, especially if they are used in several places, try to reduce the amount of structurally unnecessary parentheses, make the index structure more intuitive,....

Comment: I have made a "grid" in order to get the most "low"  starting values possible.  They are around Ubnity or ~10^1~ and  I ve tried the outmost of compact expressions (using `sy.cse`) and re defining a more complex but "quicker" function.